# orderby and order filter in get_posts or WP_query function in wordpress not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have function in wordpress plugin which queries the posts using get_posts($array). But I wanted this to orderby post_modified field of the posts table in DESCENDING order, for which I have this code below:

```
     $arrPostDtls = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'kiaarticles',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'trash','draft','auto-draft') ,
'orderby' => 'post_modified',
'order'  => 'DESC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'products',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $arrTermSlug,
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'kiacategory',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $arrCTermSlug,
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                )
            )     
            ));
```

Here, I did implemented the orderby or order clauses to get it sorted accordingly, but it doesnt work. Please suggest or help me to get the sorting as I am willing to.

**UPDATE** To get the things other way, I used the WP_query method to get the posts. for which I implemented below code:

```
$arrPostDtls = new WP_query(array(
        'post_type' => 'kiaarticles',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, //unlikely high
        'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'trash','draft','auto-draft'),
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'products',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $arrTermSlug,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'kiacategory',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $arrCTermSlug,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
        ));
```

From this I recieved the result which also contains the SQL query, and executing the SQL query in PHPmyadmin, I found the exepected result, but when i iterated the "$arrPostDtls->posts", it still gives me the old results.. Please suggest what is wrong here..

Comment: You should just be missing the `'orderby'     => 'modified',
     'order'       => 'DESC',`

Comment: @Stender sorry I updated my question with that tried code now.. I tried it already and it didnt work

Comment: So you tried changing `'orderby' => 'post_modified',` to `'orderby' => 'modified',` ?

Comment: I believe that  `"post_modified"` is only used in the function for `get_pages()` together with `'sort_column'`

Comment: changing it to 'modified' didnt work

Comment: I hope to see something after bounty :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my problem on the UI side (thanks to @Zhilevan) where by ajax response was being exposed to a jQuery library DataTable(), whose default ordering was sorting in alphabetical order. I set the ordering parameter to false as:

```
$("#someid").DataTable({"ordering":false});
```

And My results were displayed as I was willing to

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'kiaarticles',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 
        'trash','draft','auto-draft') ,
        'orderby' => array('post_modified' => 'DESC'),
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'products',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $arrTermSlug,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'kiacategory',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $arrCTermSlug,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )     
        ));
```

**Update** after you update the question

```
$arrPostDtls = new WP_query(array(
        'post_type' => 'kiaarticles',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, //unlikely high
        'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'trash','draft','auto-draft'),
        'orderby' => array('modified' => 'DESC'),
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'products',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $arrTermSlug,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'kiacategory',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $arrCTermSlug,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
));
```

Comment: @OMTheEternity what is your WP version?

Comment: WP Version 4.5.4

Comment: @OMTheEternity it seems your problem is not in order by statement, have you tried without orderby statement? do you have results?

Comment: Yes I have the results as it is.. it doesnt change by adding or removal of orderby statement

Comment: Is it possible there is some filter impacting it?

Comment: @OMTheEternity yes, of course, you can try a simple query with an order by statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163798/discussion-between-om-the-eternity-and-zhilevan).

Comment: I have updated my question with a different way of implementation, i got little closer to it but still stuck at a point, please assist.

Comment: Now I get the query as an array index, value pair which is being executed and another index as posts which is the result which I am actually expecting, But When I am irerating it on UI, I get it ordered in Alphabetical order... Cnnot figure out where it is getting impacted

Comment: @OMTheEternity so the problem is not in query , is that true?

Comment: Thats True, zhilevan

Comment: But the problem still persist.. The question was why I am getting incorrect order, even If we have orderby in place, Question was not about if my query is correct or not

Comment: @OMTheEternity down vote is my spending time reward?

Comment: @OMTheEternity by the way, I think this question is done, and your problem should be asked in another question and details about he codes after this query, because this query is work correctly and the results is the same as you want . your problem is on present the result in view.

Comment: I respect your perception, but a question is asked with a problem of output in mind, and then if that problem could be of many reasons and thats why we end up looking for reasons everywhere..

Comment: @OMTheEternity I know that dude, but we answer based on what are mentioned in question, I strongly recommend ask another question and mention this question there with details about the issue, this query in the question is done and working correctly and probably problem is in rendering